# move_uploaded_file failed to open stream: Permission denied Mac

Tags: php, image, xampp, image-uploading

I want to upload an image. Every time I try to upload the image I recieve the error message found below.

I have already set the permissions to read&write:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/1000020170620022532img3.png):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/social-network-master/profile.php
>   on line 41
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpYqSkvp' to
>   'uploads/1000020170620022532img3.png' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/social-network-master/profile.php
>   on line 41

Comment: Probably something wrong with paths or permissions. if you set permissions correctly check the paths. Maybe change them to absolute paths temporary.

Comment: welcome to SO, please consider the following: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Friend, You only need only to create the directory where are your .php file is found:

> uploads/

And change the Only write in the folder

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],'uploads/1000020170620022532img3.png');
```

If this code is not working please check path and folder permission.

Answer (score 0):

try this in terminal

```
sudo chmod -R 777 upload/
```

p.s. got to the upload directory and run **sudo chmode -R 777** directly.